# Binary classification with CNN for soccer ball detection doesn't converge

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm working on a project where I want to detect classic soccer balls in live camera pictures using a Convolutional Neural Network. My Network is built up as follows:

```
conv1: 11x11, 96, ReLU, max pooling, normalization
conv2: 5x5, 256, ReLU, max pooling, normalization
conv3: 3x3, 384, ReLU
conv4: 3x3, 384, ReLU
conv5: 3x3, 256, ReLU, max pooling, normalization
fc1: 3072, TanH, dropout 0.5
fc2: 3072, TanH, dropout 0.5
fc3: 2, softmax
momentum, categorical crossentropy, learning rate 0.001
```

I want to predict whether there is a soccer ball in a room or not, so I am using images like the following of about 200 in each class for training:

[image: Classes to predict]

Unfortunately, I cant get the model working. I tried learning rates like 0.001, 0.01-0.05 and 0.1, everything <= 0.03 results in too fast loss decrease (0.00001) and accuracy 100% but with wrong predictions afterwards. Training with >0.03 always stays around loss 0.7 and acc 0.5.

I also tried different batch sizes and converted the former color pictures to gray scale but nothing works. Shall I use other activation functions, a sigmoid last layer or are my convolutions wrong? Or is my hole 5-3-structure not practicable?

Comment: It's strange that overlearning (obtaining a high accuracy on training set but a low one on validation) is happening for **lower** values of the learning rate. Also, 400 images might be too low for the number of parameters of your network. Have you tried oversampling?